# Notification to jump to specialist content in feed

Tags: ios, notification, messages, cta

Is there a "best in class" example of how to direct users to a specific bit of content in their feed?

I am working on a pilot app that curates articles for students and I am looking for an effective CTA to jump down to unread submitted content from the students university. This will also need to disappear and adapt depending on how many unread articles have been submitted by their university.

So far my thinking is along these lines:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a user I hate so much this type of notification, just the bubble on the feed it's enough to make I click there because I don't like to have notifications bubble on my screen.

But if this is so important for your company I did a suggestion:

[image: When entering on the app you can show this notification open for 10 seconds or until client click to close]

[image: When click to close, hide the big notification and keep the bubble there]

When click click on the notification or on the feed you should show the 5 articles that you have for your user.

Independent how do you decide to use, **please don't move the content like your current one**, just show some notice over the content with close button apparently and on settings give the opportunity to enable this.